# Environment variables for javac source/target

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, javac

I'm getting error from javac when building with maven/ant

```
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 5
[javac] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[javac] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

From what I found I could in theory run it as `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6` but the problem is that script that is running it is auto-generated (I'm trying to build thrift-0.11.0).

Is there any environment variable or some immutable place (settings file) where I could configure source and target?

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hi @Sebap123, i know it s been a few years, but do you remember if you found a solution? ;-)